# How do you delete a free Google Apps account?

Tags: google-workspace

I have looked over the [article regarding deleting your Google Apps account](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1257646) many times, but after attempting to follow the steps, there is no visible way to delete the account. My admin console looks like this:

[image: (image)]

When I go to "Company Profile", there is no visible option to delete the account on any of the tabs (which are *Profile*, *Communication Preferences*, *Personalization and Custom URLS*). I have tried selecting the gear icon to the right hand side of the page, but this only contains a 'Setup' button. After going to and completing the setup, clicking the hyperlink to it now shows this page:
[image: Setup page]

On my Google account control panel, there is no button to remove the account and the data associated with it but this was noted in another [Google support article](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32046?hl=en).

Is there a period of time to wait before deleting an account, or is this just a small flaw in Google?

Comment: So, you have already read the [google help page](https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1257646) on this?

Comment: Did you purchase your domain through a Google domain registration partner?

Comment: @demure Yes, as specified at the top of the post I have already read the article.

Comment: @batpigandme I purchased the domain through Namecheap, who as far as I know are not partnered with Google.

Comment: What shows up when you click the setup button from the gear dropdown? Also, can you link to the other support articles you reference in your question (just edit the question itself)?

Comment: @batpigandme I have edited the question with an image and links to the articles (I could not originally do this due to my reputation).

Comment: Have you deleted your domains & all users (other than the admin user)?

Answer (score 3):

After some fumbling around, I found under company profile, if you scroll to the bottom of the RHS there is a delete account option.
First I had to delete the managed apps

Comment: What is RHS? I've never seen that in my Google Apps control panel.

Comment: I guess right-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a walk through video from Google on how to remove the domain.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UGWK6bPyz68

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. - [How do I write a good answer?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)